# Ubuntu 14.04: Converting a `pdf` file to `ps` format

Tags: 14.04, pdf, conversion, ps

I want to convert `pdf` file to `ps` file and used the following command in `Ubuntu 14.04`

```
pdf2ps input.pdf output.ps
```

But this command throws the following error:

```
sfopen: gs_parse_file_name failed.
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1031: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find srgb.icc
```

Any idea to fix this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It seems a [bug](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695046)

Comment: @Letizia: Any solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I would try GhostScript:

gs 
-o repaired.pdf 
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen 
your_original.pdf

or "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress" according the quality you wants.